# Android tabHost images

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I did [this source](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/android-tabactivity-tab-layout-demo-tab.html?showComment=1396423315399#c553770771119550017). It works but i cant see images on tabs. Can you help me about it ?

I solve it. Changed ic_tab xmls like it.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- When selected, you should use bg with grey -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" >
        <!-- <layer-list> -->
        <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1_over"/> -->
        <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/camera"/> -->
        <!-- </layer-list> -->

<layer-list>
            <item android:left="0dp" android:width="0dp"><bitmap android:gravity="top" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/home" />
            </item>
        </layer-list></item>

    <!-- When not selected, you should use bg with white -->
        <item>

    <layer-list>
            <item android:left="0dp" android:width="0dp"><bitmap android:gravity="top" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/home2" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>

        </item>
</selector>
```

But how can i change tab text position ?

Comment: Can't help you like this. Re-check your code and image resource names. You many find solution yourself. If Images, are of higher resolution, they are prone to show weirdly in Tabhost.

Comment: I checked everything 2 times. But i didn't find any problem :/